# Streaming Javascript Objects from child process to parent

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream

Is there an easy way to stream nodejs objects from a child process to the parent?  I am trying to break a long pipeline that streams objects through various processing components.  I now want to break up the chain and have part of it in a child process.  I have no issue piping stdout from the child to the parent, but that's with strings and buffers.  I know I could use JSON.stringify on the sending side and JSON.parse on the receiving side, but is there another way?

Comment: You can't directly move Javascript objects between processes (as they are completely different instances of V8 operating in different process memory) so they have to be serialized and then deserialized in some fashion (JSON is typically used for this serialization).

Comment: So, in other words, `JSON.parse()` and `JSON.stringify()` are likely what you would use unless you want to invent your own serialization format.

Comment: Thank you @jfriend00.  I kinda thought that was the case, but as I've had limited experience in js, I wanted to check to make sure.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't directly move Javascript objects between processes (as they are completely different instances of V8 operating in different process memory) so they have to be serialized and then deserialized in some fashion (JSON is typically used for this serialization).

> Is there an easy way to stream nodejs objects from a child process to the parent?

You can use [`process.send(someObj)`](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_send_message_sendhandle_options_callback) to send an object from the child to the parent and nodejs will do the serialization and deserialization for you (cloning the object into the parent process).  The object needs to be pure Javascript (so no references to native code stuff) and without circular references, but can otherwise be any pure Javascript object.

This is sent over an IPC channel that nodejs automatically sets up between parent and child when the child process is created.  Per the doc, "Messages will be received as a 'message' event on the parent's ChildProcess object."

Comment: Thanks again.  I ended up using the IPC channel method.  Works great for what I'm doing.